# get the value of the deepest nested dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary like

```py
{a:{b:{c:{d:2}}}, e:2, f:2}
```

How am I supposed to get the value of d and change it in python? Previous questions only showed how to get the level of nesting but didn't show how to get the value. In this case, I do not know the level of nesting of the dict. Any help will be appreciated, thank you!!!
P.S. I am using python 3

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple dicts in your dict? That is, does the solution need to first find the deepest dict out of all the dicts and then only change the deepest one?

Comment: If the input were  `{'a':{'b':{'c':{'d':2}}}, 'e':{'a':{'b':{'c':{'d':2}}}}, 'f':2}`what should it return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about some recursion?

```
def unest(data, key):
    if key in data.keys():
        return data.get(key)
    else:
        for dkey in data.keys():
            if isinstance(data.get(dkey), dict):
                return unest(data.get(dkey), key)
            else:
                continue

d = {'a':{'b':{'c':{'d':25}}}, 'e':2, 'f':2}

r = unest(d, 'd')
# 25

r = unest(d, 'c')
# {'d': 25}
```

Edit: As Paul Rooney points out we don't have to use `data.keys`, we can simply iterate over the keys by doing `if key in data`

Edit 2: Given the input you provided this would find the deepest level, however this does not cover certain cases, such as where for example, key `e` is also a nested dictionary that goes `n + 1` levels where `n` is equal to the depth of key `a`.

```
def find_deepest(data):
    if not any([isinstance(data.get(k), dict) for k in data]):
        return data
    else:
        for dkey in data:
            if isinstance(data.get(dkey), dict):
                return find_deepest(data.get(dkey))
            else:
                continue

u = find_deepest(d)
# {'d': 2}
```

Comment: yes you're correct, however it might be easier for a beginner to understand that I am iterating over the keys in the dictionary

Comment: you answered a long time ago, but this solidified the concept of recursion in my head, thank you!

Comment: @ArjunArun glad this answer helped you!

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for a similar solution, but I wanted to find the deepest instance of any key within a (possibly) nested dictionary and return it's value. This assumes you know what key you want to search for ahead of time. It's unclear to me if that is a valid assumption for the original question, but I hope this will help others if they stumble on this thread.

```
def find_deepest_item(obj, key, deepest_item = None):
if key in obj: 
    deepest_item = obj[key]
for k, v in obj.items():
    if isinstance(v,dict):
        item = find_deepest_item(v, key, deepest_item)
        if item is not None:
            deepest_item = item
return deepest_item
```

In this example, the 'd' key exists at the top level as well:

```
d = {'a':{'b':{'c':{'d':25}}}, 'd':3, 'e':2, 'f':2}
v = find_deepest_item(d, 'd')
# 25
```

Search for 'c':

```
v = find_deepest_item(d, 'c')
# {'d': 25}
```